# No comprendo el e--

Tags: java

La primera iteración e no es mayor que 0 , por lo que el `result` es 1. Bien perfecto y las siguientes iteraciones va usando el `result` acumulado siendo siempre e mayor que 0 pero, Porque e--?. si pongo e++ da siempre como resultado 0.

```java
class Power {   
  public static void main(String args[]) { 


    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
     int result = 1; 
     int e = i; 
      while(e > 0) { 
        result *= 2; 
        e--; 
      } 

      System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  
                         " power is " + result);        
    } 
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Veamos que pasa si no se ocupa `e`, ni el `while`

```java
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
     int result = 1; 
     //int e = i; 
     //while(e > 0) { 
        result *= 2; 
       // e--; 
     //} 

      System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  
                         " power is " + result);        
}
```

El resultado siempre será 2:

> Resultado

```
2 to the 0 power is 2
2 to the 1 power is 2
2 to the 2 power is 2
2 to the 3 power is 2
2 to the 4 power is 2
2 to the 5 power is 2
2 to the 6 power is 2
2 to the 7 power is 2
2 to the 8 power is 2
2 to the 9 power is 2
```

---

### Ahora, ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Para mostrar la potencia correctamente, en este caso la variable `e` tomará el valor de `i` en cada iteración y se comprobará en el ciclo `while` que `e` sea mayor a 0, entonces, cada vez que la iteración cambia, se entra al ciclo `while` y se repite el código de su interior hasta que la condición definida se cumpla:

> Supongamos que `i` tiene el valor 8

```java
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { //se encuentra en la iteración 8
     int result = 1; //resultado siempre será 1, en cada iteración
     int e = i; //e toma el valor de i, que en teoría el 8
     while(e > 0) { //es ciclo se repetira hasta que e sea mayor a 0, es decir, hasta que e sea 0, esto se rompe
        result *= 2; //mientras la condición se cumpla, esto se repetirá 8 veces de 7 a 0
        e--; // se resta una unidad a la variable e
     } 


      System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  
                         " power is " + result);// Aquí el resultado será 256  
}
```

- En cada iteración del ciclo `while`, `e` irá disminuyendo un valor, hasta llegar a 0, y el ciclo se romperá.
- Como el ciclo `while` se repite hasta que e llegue a 0. Esta línea:

```java
 result *= 2;
```

Se ejecuta las veces equivalentes al exponente.

Answer (score 1):

El uso de la variable `e` es para hacer funcionar el algoritmo en el caso x^0 = 1; dentro del for.

El código puede simplificarse para ser más entendible de la siguiente forma:

```
   //El caso de excepción x^0 = 1 se calcula fuera del for
   System.out.println("2 to the 0 power is 1" );

    int result = 1;
    //En el for se calculan los casos normales
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 

     result *= 2;

      System.out.println("2 to the " + i +  " power is " + result);        
    }
```